# Batch file and YUI Compressor

Tags: batch-file, yui

How would I add the YUI compressor into this

```
@echo off
echo Combining.....
type lib\css\header.css>>stylesheet.css
type lib\css\footer.css>>stylesheet.css
echo Finished!
PAUSE
```

I would like it in simple terms so that I can understand how it works please, I've downloaded the latest build of YUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command for use YUI is :

```
java -jar yuicompressor.jar original.css -o original.min.css
```

Try this but specify the path of yuicompressor.jar :

```
@echo off
echo Combining.....
type lib\css\header.css>>stylesheet.css
type lib\css\footer.css>>stylesheet.css
java -jar /path/to/yuicompressor.jar stylesheet.css -o stylesheet.min.css
echo Finished!
PAUSE
```